# Declare type list argument in F#

Tags: list, f#

I am building a simple function that compares two lists and returns `true` if the first list is a prefix of the second one.
Expected signature:

```
prefix: int list -> int list -> bool
```

For example:

```
prefix [1; 2] [1; 2; 3; 4] --> true
prefix [ ] [1;2] --> true
prefix [2] [1;2;3] --> false
```

Right now, I am at this step:

```
let prefix l1 l2 =
        match l1 with
        | (l1, l2) when (l1.[0] = l2.[0]) -> true
        | _ -> false
```

I think I could be on the right way, but I got this error:

```
 The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of
    indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding 
    further type constraints
```

How can I declare in `prefix` that `l1` and `l2` are lists? I looked for a solution [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists) but the problem is probably so trivial that I there is not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the last part of your question about declaring that types are lists (since the other parts were answered already), we use "type annotations".  They look like `(name : type)` in a function argument, such as

```
let prefix (l1 : _ list) (l2 : _ list) = ...
```

That will declare both `l1` and `l2` as lists of the some type that the compiler will infer.  You can replace the `_` with a specific or generic type too, as you see fit.

For implementing your function by hand, remember you'll have to go further than just comparing the first element - you'll need to recurse through the lists.

```
let prefix l1 l2 =
    let rec loop = function
        | [], _ -> true
        | _, [] -> false
        | h1 :: _, h2 :: _ when h1 <> h2 -> false
        | _ :: t1, _ :: t2 -> loop (t1, t2)
    loop (l1, l2)
```

This version does not need type annotations at all, because the pattern matches inside `loop` constrain both arguments to be of type `'a list`.  If you wanted your function to be explicitly for only `int list`s, though, you could instead start it with

```
let prefix (l1 : int list) l2 =
```

You would only need to annotate one argument, because the other is constrained to be of the same type.

Comment: Thank you Jake, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a generic List function for this:

```
let prefix l1 l2 =
    List.compareWith (fun x y -> if x = y then 0 else 1) l1 l2 < 0
```

Comment: Very practical approach, thank you! Apart from brevity, what makes this approach preferable on the approach in Jake Lishman's answer?

Comment: @Worice I'm not that experienced to tell the exact difference, but I imagine that the repeatedly split in head and tail and the recursive call itself may be rather expensive compared to a probably iterative compare of two entries?

Comment: The split of head and tail is just syntactic sugar and has no overhead. The recursive call is tail-recursive, and in this case will be compiled into a loop rather than a recursive call anyway. If that sort of code were not performant, F# wouldn't have much of a fanbase. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

When you use `l.[0]` you are actually trying to use arrays.

I would use something like

```
|(h1::t1,h2::t2) when h1=h2 -> true
```

but here, the matching isn't really what you want - you need

```
match (l1,l2) with
```

because you are matching over both lists

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Forgive my ignorance, but what does (h1::t1) mean? Tail and head?

Comment: yes - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching

Comment: Lists do have index access as well, not just arrays.